# Snowflake schema's not visible after granting database usage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Running the following statements:

```
use role accountadmin;
create role my_role;
grant role my_role to user my_user;

use role SYSADMIN;
create database tst_db;
grant usage on database tst_db to role my_role;
```

I would expect the `public` and `information_schema` to be visible to the role `my_role`, however they do not show up.

What grants are required for them to show up for `my_role`?

Answer (score 1):

Granting explicitly access to `PUBLIC` schema:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tst_db.PUBLIC TO ROLE my_role;
```